# GPS coordinates using network

Tags: android, networking, gps

I am currently working with GPS in my android application.My questions are,  1.Is GPRS  needed to get gps coordinates,if want to get coordinates without GPS?  2.What are the settings need to be enabled to to work with gps coordinates using network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want geographical coordinates as pair: latitude, longitude. (not GPS coordinates)

Such coordinates and other attributes can be delivered either by GPS, WLAN or Cell-Tower locating.

For WLAN and Cell-Tower (Network) locating you need an internet connection.

For GPS Locationg Provider, ususally you don't need any network (GSM) but there are  some Android phones that are strange designed, such that GPS does not work without having an Internet connection while starting GPS.

If you want network locating, you can explicitly set the Location Provider. Set it to NETWORK_PROVIDER:

```
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}
```

Comment: Used above mentioned code.Used necessary permissions fine,coarse in manifest file.And enabled "Use wireless networks" in Location & Security settings. Disabled GPS,WiFi and GPRS since i want to use only sim.But onLocationChanged never getting called in my location listener.Do i miss anything?

Comment: Try if it works with GPRS; remember it will need 30-40s to get first Location , if you have good view to sky; GSM (without GPRS) is probably to slow. The phone has to call an Android Internet server to get the coordinates related to the GSM-Cell id you are booked in.

Comment: Thanks and it works with gprs.So what you mean is that i need internet connection to get geographical coordinates.But what if i dont have gprs or wifi enabled in my mobile.Moreover, why should i go outside or expose my mobile under sky if at all i get coordinates via gprs(internet), since we could access mobile internet inside room? How can i get those coordinates just via SIM? and this is the requirement what i actually have.

Comment: If your phone books into the next GSM Cell radio tower, then this tower has an id, but no coordinate. This id is sent via internet to an Android(or other company) which has a world wide data base of GSM-Cell id to coordinate. This server sends back the geo coordinate. Therefore you need Internet, or you use GPS.

Answer (score 1):

> Is GPRS needed to get gps coordinates

Answer: Not necessary if you are not using map.

But you have to use following permissions to work with GPS.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

> What are the settings need to be enabled to to work with gps coordinates using network

Only enable your wi-fi and GPS on device.

Comment: Do i need to enable GPS,if at all i want to get gps coordinates using network?I want to get gps coordinates even when gps is not enabled.

Comment: at this stage network_provider will help you which gets location data from network but not powerful as gps.

Answer (score 1):

To 1.: GPRS and GPS do not have anything in common. GPRS is a protocol for mobile internet, whereas GPS is for positioning you're phone. GPS doesn't need internet to work!

Anyways, most smartphones nowadays have Assisted GPS (A-GPS), which basically works as normal GPS (without any internet connection), but CAN retrieve information about the GPS satellites via internet for a faster location fix. GPS should still work without any internet connection as far as I know, but maybe there are really provider out there, who messed with the protocol so badly.

Long story short: GPS doesn't need internet!

To 2.: as I mentioned above, you don't need any internet for GPS, so that

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

should work.

But you're question sounds like you wanna obtain coordinates via network positioning. In that case you would need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

But: ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION is already implied by ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION